# Recibir parametros en php desde httpclient de angular

Tags: php, angular

Intento mandar un usuario y una clave a php mediante httpclient de angular, pero cuando hago un echo al usuario o a la clave me da null. 
El resultado del echo es `{usuario:"miusuario",clave:"miclave"}` Esto es correcto pero me gustaría saber como acceder directamente a la variable usuario o clave.

He leído que desde php hay que poner `$var = file_get_contents("php://input");`

**Archivo php**

```
$d = file_get_contents("php://input");
 echo $d;
```

**Metodo en angular**

```
 postLogin(usuario,clave)//Metodo post
    { 
     this.usuario=usuario;
     this.clave=clave;

   const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     var body:any = {
      "usuario":usuario,
      "clave":clave
      };

      this.httpclient.post(this.url, body ,{headers})
        .subscribe(
          (data:any)=>{
            console.log(data)
          }
        )
      }
    }
```

He intentado echo `$d["usuario"];` para acceder directamente al campo usuario pero recibo un error

Comment: estás enviando y recibiendo un json, en php tendrás que decodificarlo con `json_decode`

Comment: Yo te recomiendo aprender a usar algún framework como laravel lumen https://webtraining.zone/eventos/creacion-de-un-restful-api-con-laravel-lumen es una belleza hacer api's con esa herramienta una vez que aprendes a usarla https://lumen.laravel.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui pongo lo que he tenido que hacer para recibir las variables en php.
También pongo el código de angular.

**Angular**

```
postLogin(usuario: any,clave: any)
{ 
 this.usuario=usuario;
 this.clave=clave;

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 var body:any = {
  "usuario":usuario,
  "clave":clave
  };


  this.httpclient.post(this.url, body ,{headers})
    .subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Php**

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $usuario= $data->usuario; 
    $clave= $data->clave;
```